# How to display the defined amount of textboxes dynamically in separate class for few forms?

Tags: c#, sqlite, class, controls

I have SQLite database wherein there is a table with some quantity of rows. I have a task to display the same quantity of textboxes in few forms with taking into account the coordinates of these controls. The names of these textboxes should be taken from one of the columns of this table.  Also the labels must be present. Their names should be similar. Taking into account the fact the values of this column of this table is cyrillic I have decided to translate it into latinic symbols in the class Decryptor.

I've found the solution to perform the focus of displaying necessary textboxes in one form and I am able to copy this code into other forms. But it isn't good idea it seems despite the fact it would work in this case.

I've created new class - CommunicationCanalsDrawing. The idea of this class is reduction of code quantity and incresing of the usage convinience of this code. My code of particular class:

```
class CommunicationCanalsDrawing
{
    public int Tx { get; set; }
    public int Ty { get; set; }
    public int Lx { get; set; }
    public int Ly { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public string[] Labels;
    private string[] Textboxes;

    public TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    public Label l = new Label();

    public int i { get; set; }

    public void DrawThat()
    {
        Ly += 32;
        Ty += 32;
        Decryptor decr = new Decryptor();
        decr.Word = Labels[i];
        Textboxes[i] = decr.Decrypt();
        txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Name = Textboxes[i];
        txt.Text = "";
        txt.Width = Width;
        txt.Height = Height;
        txt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F,
            System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
            ((byte)(204)));
        txt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Tx, Ty);

        l = new Label();
        l.Name = "l_" + Textboxes[i];
        l.Text = Labels[i];
        l.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F,
            System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
            ((byte)(204)));
        l.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(Lx, Ly);
    }

    public void ListOfColumns()
    {
        SQLiteConnection m_dbConn = new SQLiteConnection();
        SQLiteCommand m_sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand();
        int AmountTextbox = 0;
        try
        {
            InceptDb cl = new InceptDb();
            m_dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" +
                cl.dbFileName + ";Version=3;");
            m_dbConn.Open();
            m_sqlCmd.Connection = m_dbConn;

            m_sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM communication_remedies";
            AmountTextbox = Convert.ToInt32(m_sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error count*: " + ex.Message);
        }
        m_dbConn.Close();

        if (AmountTextbox == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Довідник каналів зв'язку пустий.");
            Organizations o = new Organizations();
            o.Close();
        }

        m_dbConn = new SQLiteConnection();
        m_sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand();

        Labels = new string[AmountTextbox];
        Textboxes = new string[AmountTextbox];

        try
        {
            InceptDb cl = new InceptDb();
            m_dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" +
                cl.dbFileName + ";Version=3;");
            m_dbConn.Open();
            m_sqlCmd.Connection = m_dbConn;

            m_sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM communication_remedies";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(m_sqlCmd.CommandText,
                m_dbConn);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            Labels =
                dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("name")).ToArray();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error count*: " + ex.Message);
        }
        m_dbConn.Close();
        }
        }
```

My code of some form:

```
private void Organizations_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CommunicationCanalsDrawing comm = new CommunicationCanalsDrawing();

        comm.ListOfColumns();

        comm.Lx = 12;
        comm.Tx = 243;
        comm.Ty = 173;
        comm.Ly = 207;
        comm.Height = 26;
        comm.Width = 228;
        for (int i = 0; i < comm.Labels.Length; i++ )
        {
            comm.i = i;
            comm.DrawThat();
            this.Controls.Add(comm.txt);
            this.Controls.Add(comm.l);
        }
    }
```

I know the coordinates of the controls can be incorrect, but it does not matter now. It's easy to rectify. I see only the last textbox and the last label. Others aren't displayed.

Comment: You need to add the controls to the form, `this.Controls.Add(comm.txt);` this is adding **the same** control.

Comment: The structure has some flaws, `public TextBox txt = new TextBox();` and `txt = new TextBox();` you are constructing the textbox twice. You should separate the Communication and generating of controls. I advise you, when you have multiple controls to generate, put them into a usercontrol.

Comment: But every step in this cycle it seems I add absolutely another control. Because the coordinates and other parameters including name are another. Isn't it?

Comment: No every step is generating a control, but they are never added. you only add the last one over and over. `CommunicationCanalsDrawing comm` is one instance. `this.Controls.Add(comm.txt);` this is adding the same instance over and over

Comment: I've noticed that I cannot link to the class Organizations from the class CommunicationCanalsDrawing because I link to the second class from the first. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Instead of generating the controls in the communication class, return the DataTable. Then use the DataTable to generate controls. Also selecting a Count is not useful, just fill the datatable and check the rowcount

Comment: You should be making a custom `UserControl`. Call it `LabelAndTextBox` and then work with a single list of those controls as opposed to manually juggling a bunch of independent labels and text boxes. Or possibly use a grid or list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are creating only once instance of CommunicationCanalsDrawing and then doing your for loop on its properties. That way you end up with only the last. You need to create a new instance of CommunicationCanalsDrawing on each cycle through the for loop:

```
private void Organizations_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     for (int i = 0; i < comm.Labels.Length; i++ )
     {
        CommunicationCanalsDrawing comm = new CommunicationCanalsDrawing();

        comm.ListOfColumns();

        comm.Lx = 12;
        comm.Tx = 243;
        comm.Ty = 173;
        comm.Ly = 207;
        comm.Height = 26;
        comm.Width = 228;
        
            comm.i = i;
            comm.DrawThat();
            this.Controls.Add(comm.txt);
            this.Controls.Add(comm.l);
        }
    }
```